# iOS adding multiple URL Schemes Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building an iOS application with swift. When It's redirecting for OAuth. It stuck on below attached image. 
[web page after twitter authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dab1M.png) and it's not redirecting back to application

```
        TwitterClient.SharedInstance.requestSerializer.removeAccessToken()
    TwitterClient.SharedInstance.fetchRequestTokenWithPath("oauth/request_token", method: "POST", callbackURL: NSURL(string: "http://my.vixxxxxxxp.com:2403/auth/twitter, twitterClient://oauth-callback"), scope: nil, success: { (requestToken: BDBOAuth1Credential!) -> Void in

        print("got the token request", requestToken.token)

        let authURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=\(requestToken.token)")
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(authURL!)

        }) { (error: NSError!) -> Void in
            print("failed to  get the token request")
            print(error)
    }
```

and this is how i have added URL Schemes in info.plist 'twitterClient://oauth-callback'

It's not right. I would want to know the right way of adding  it.